# Warm Atmega328p and weird power behaviour

Tags: power, atmega328

I recently built a circuit with an atmega328p (which I have never used before standalone) and attached all the neccessary components (crystal, capacitors etc). However, when I powered it up with a regulated 5v input, I noticed the chip getting a little bit warm. Not hot, the temperature seems quite constant, and everything still works just fine. Another strange thing though, is when I connect the VCC to AVCC together as specified in the datasheet, the circuit doesn't work at all: The LCD screen just shows solid blocks at the top. When I disconnect the wire again, everything is back to normal. What went wrong? It is perfectly possible that there is a small solder bridge on my perfboard.

Comment: Please say more about your "circuit with an atmega328p", such as what is connected to the MCU and how. Running warm suggests you may be trying to supply to much current to other devices through the MCU. A schematic would help; so would  part numbers for the external devices, such as the LCD which you only mentioned in passing.

Comment: Do you have a multimeter, so you can measure the current usage? Could you post an image of your setup, or a schematic?

Comment: Current Usage at 10v (going into 5V regulator) is 0.01 milliamperes

Comment: LCD is just a generic 16x2 LCD I got on ebay, I have used it with an Arduino uno for a long time with no issues.

Comment: What kind of regulator did you use? Current input doesn't necessarily tell you about the current consumption of the board and, by itself, nothing about MCU current. In fact the regulator circuit on an Arduino board would disispate a great deal of the current drawn from a 10v supply. And 10 micro-amps? Really? Schematic please.

Comment: @JRobert  I cannot provide a schematic because I didn't make one. The atmega chip still heats up even when there is nothing connected at all. I have double checked that the crystal and ceramic capacitors are wired properly and they are. The voltage regulator is one that I salvaged from an old power supply. I provided it with 19v for about 10 minutes (which is the voltage that I will be using) and it heated up to the point that I couldn't touch it, even though the datasheet says this is well within its recommended range. The read on my bench psu said 0.01 amps.(not milliamps, my mistake)

Comment: I also tried powering it from an arduino uno board and although I can upload code and everything works properly, the chip still warms up.

Comment: I think you have to add more details about your circuit before anyone could see what's your problem, plus are you sure from that voltage regulator you salvaged? it can be a wrong value regulator, I recommend buying one or telling us it's name or number, lastly supplying a 19V to a 5V linear voltage regulator is BAD because those volts will be dissipated as heat that could rise dramatically till you couldn't touch, use lower voltage or just use a buck converter which will be ultimately better.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I have hooked the board directly to 5V power supply and the chip draws 0.1 amps